# QR Code contains TAB that sets focus on the next object in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-scanner

I have created a program that uses a Powerscan PD9530 scanner to register serialnumbers of different parts into a database. But one of the parts contains TAB between different parts of the serialnumber. I need to get the entire serialnumber into a selected TextBox, but the TABS in the QR-Code makes the focus jump to the next TextBox and presses some buttons as it jumps along.

My Program is able to identify what part is scanned to put it in the right location in the database.

The serialnumber format is like this: "+    002761  M0610500HQ  000001917   "
with the spaces being TAB

I have tried:

```
private void TxtPa_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            txtPa.Focus();
        }
     }
```

I was hoping that this would set the focus back to the TxtPa TextBox when the TAB space get input, but the next piece of numbers after the TAB gets put into the next TextBox instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how QR code data is being consumed by your program? It sounds like a forms application taking the data as if someone typed it?

Comment: Im not sure how the Scanner writes it, if it is all at once, or if it writes it like someone typed it, but it has an Enter command that always gets executed after reading the code wich is fine, but when it reads TAB in the QR Code it executes that as if TAB was pressed on the keyboard

Comment: The Program just reads whats been written in the TextBox

Comment: Enable [AcceptsTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_TextBoxBase_AcceptsTab) on the text box that has focus when you scan.

Comment: It sounds like the QR code reader is somehow tied into the keyboard loop on your form. You need to understand how that works. You may be on the right track with your key-down event - there are other keyboard related events - it depends on which forms system you're working with (web, winforms, wpf, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added "e.Enabled = true;"  and it helped me somewhat. It doesn't jump to the next object, but it only reads the last part of the serialnumber "000001917". The string value is added like this: string OSRAM = txtPa.txt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out thanks to your help.

I added "e.Enabled = true" and it pretty much solved my initial problem.

I only had to declare the String that read from the TextBox outside the function

```
string OSRAM = "";
private void TxtPa_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
       OSRAM = OSRAM + " " + txtPa.Text;
            serl[5] = OSRAM;              
            e.Handled = true;
    }
 }
```

Thank you very much for the help